# Only getting first row in pandas Dataframe with getvalueofnode(node.find())

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have made an API call and want to loop through the response xml to extract the relevant values to a dataframe. The code has worked fine earlier, but now it apparentely does not want to return more than the first value per node/column.

This is my response XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Assets xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <IsLastPage>true</IsLastPage>
    <AssetRecords>
        <Asset url="https://api.myvisionlink.com/APIService/VLReady/assets/single/1486128866430645">
            <VisionLinkIdentifier>1486128866430645</VisionLinkIdentifier>
            <MakeCode>CAT</MakeCode>
            <MakeName>CAT</MakeName>
            <SerialNumber>PNL00585</SerialNumber>
            <AssetID>10-143</AssetID>
            <EquipmentVIN/>
            <Model>320ELRR</Model>
            <ProductFamily>TRACK EXCAVATORS</ProductFamily>
            <ManufactureYear>2015</ManufactureYear>
        </Asset>
        <Asset url="https://api.myvisionlink.com/APIService/VLReady/assets/single/2278960667345107">
            <VisionLinkIdentifier>2278960667345107</VisionLinkIdentifier>
            <MakeCode>CAT</MakeCode>
            <MakeName>CAT</MakeName>
            <SerialNumber>HBT20130</SerialNumber>
            <AssetID>10-160</AssetID>
            <EquipmentVIN/>
            <Model>330FL</Model>
```

etc.

And this is my code:

```
r = session.get("https://api.myvisionlink.com/APIService/VLReady/Assets/1", headers={'Content-Type':'application/xml'})


def getvalueofnode(node):
    return node.text if node is not None else None

def main():
   root = cET.fromstring(r.content)
   ns = {"xsd":"http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/position",
         "xsi":"http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/common/position"}

   data_list = [{'Make': getvalueofnode(node.find('Asset/MakeName', ns)),
                 'SerialNumber': getvalueofnode(node.find('Asset/SerialNumber', ns)),
                 'AssetID': getvalueofnode(node.find('Asset/AssetID', ns)),
                 'Model': getvalueofnode(node.find('Asset/Model', ns)),
                 'ProductFamily': getvalueofnode(node.find('Asset/ProductFamily', ns)),
                 'ManufactureYear': getvalueofnode(node.find('Asset/ManufactureYear', ns))} for node in root]

   global df_xml
   df_xml = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

main()
```

The resulting DataFrame I get is as follows:[image: Response code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the result you're getting back from your API call, but the xml looks malformed in the sample your provided with your question. Your code would have worked if the structure of the XML was different say if the asset elements were in the root of your XML structure.

The reason you're only getting the first record is because you're iterating through the "IsLastPage" element and the "AssetRecords" element, and since you're using find() and not findall() it is stopping once it finds the first match. If you want to continue to use find() and not findall() you have to modify your code to iterate through the "AssetRecords" element which is what I modified in your code below.

```
def main():
   root = et.fromstring(xml)
   ns = {"xsd":"http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/position",
         "xsi":"http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/common/position"}

   # Find AssetRecords element
   asset_records = root.find("AssetRecords")

   data_list = [{'Make': getvalueofnode(node.find('MakeName', ns)),
                 'SerialNumber': getvalueofnode(node.find('SerialNumber', ns)),
                 'AssetID': getvalueofnode(node.find('AssetID', ns)),
                 'Model': getvalueofnode(node.find('Model', ns)),
                 'ProductFamily': getvalueofnode(node.find('ProductFamily', ns)),
                 'ManufactureYear': getvalueofnode(node.find('ManufactureYear', ns))} for node in asset_records]

   global df_xml
   df_xml = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```

```
Output:
 Make SerialNumber AssetID    Model     ProductFamily ManufactureYear
0  CAT     PNL00585  10-143  320ELRR  TRACK EXCAVATORS            2015
1  CAT     HBT20130  10-160    330FL  TRACK EXCAVATORS            2015
```

Hope that answers your question, if you need me to clarify anything please let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks @Christopher Lee, it is working now. Great with your explanation, I am still very new to Python and code.

Comment: @JonasH Yeah don't worry man, we were all in the same position at some point in time. :)